# Calculate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-2)}dx$ using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm supposed to calculate

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-2)}dx$$

using residues. The typical procedure on a problem like this would be to integrate a contour going around an upper-half semicircle of radius $R$, and come back through the real axis, taking two indents on the path at the points $z=-1$, $z=2$, say of radius $\rho_1,\rho_2$ respectively. Then the total integral around the path is $0$ and I can calculate the limits as $\rho_1,\rho_2\to0$ and $R\to\infty$ using the known formulas/theorems. However, this leaves me with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-2)}dx$, instead of $0$ to $\infty$. And the function is not even so I can't just take half of the whole integral.

Does anybody know a way around this problem? Taking a path going a quarter around the circle and back down to the origin seems unnecessarily complicated, and I'm not even sure that would work here.

Comment: This integral does not converge in the usual sense; that said, we can assign a *principal value* to it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: @Travis how would I show it doesn't converge in the usual sense? It seems strange he'd word the problem as if the integral did converge. Also, isn't the principal value for when we'd like to define $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R f(x)dx$? Why does this apply to the integral from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Writing the integral in terms of indefinite integrals gives $\lim_{a \to 2^-} \int_0^a \frac{dx}{(x + 1) (x - 2)} + \cdots$, and this limit does not converge. The p.v. also applies to a singularity on the domain of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use, as Jack said, a keyhole contour with bumps above and below the pos. real axis at $z=2$.  Thus, if $C$ is that keyhole contour with the bumps of radius $\epsilon$, we consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log{z}}{(z+1)(z-2)}$$

which is equal to (assuming we have taken the radius of the large circular arc to go to $\infty$)

$$PV \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{(x+1)(x-2)} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\log{(2+\epsilon e^{i \phi}})}{(3+ \epsilon e^{i \phi})(e^{i \phi})} \\ + PV \int_{\infty}^0 dx \frac{\log{x}+i 2 \pi}{(x+1)(x-2)} + i \epsilon \int_{2 \pi}^{\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\log{(2+\epsilon e^{i \phi})+i 2 \pi}}{(3+ \epsilon e^{i \phi})(e^{i \phi})} $$

The contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=e^{i \pi}$.  Thus,

$$-i 2 \pi PV \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{(x+1)(x-2)} - i 2 \pi \frac{\log{2}}{3} + \frac{2 \pi^2}{3} = i 2 \pi \frac{i \pi}{-3}$$

Therefore we now say that

$$PV \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{(x+1)(x-2)}  = - \frac{\log{2}}{3} $$

Answer (score 6):

The integrand function has a simple pole at $z=2$, hence the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{(z+1)(z-2)}\,dx $$
is not converging in the usual Riemann- or Lebesgue-sense. However, if $\gamma_r$ is a key-hole contour from $0$ to $R\in(4,+\infty)$ in the right half-plane that avoids $z=2$ with a small semi-circular bulge having radius $r$, 
[image]

we may consider:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{r\to 0}\oint_{\gamma_r}\frac{dz}{(z+1)(z-2)}&=&\frac{1}{3}\lim_{r\to 0}\oint_{\gamma_r}\left(\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z+1}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{4}^{R}\frac{dz}{z-2}-\int_{0}^{R}\frac{dz}{z+1}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{2}^{R-2}\frac{dz}{z}-\int_{1}^{R+1}\frac{dz}{z}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{3}\left(-\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dz}{z}-\int_{R-2}^{R+1}\frac{dz}{z}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{-\frac{\log 2}{3}}+O\left(\frac{1}{R}\right).\end{eqnarray*} $$
By letting $R\to +\infty$, we have that $\color{red}{-\frac{\log 2}{3}}$ is the **principal value** (PV) of the given integral.

Comment: By key-hole contour, do you mean something looking like this? https://www.google.com/search?q=keyhole+contour&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=627&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ5-e7uqzMAhUD6CYKHboVBpoQ_AUICCgD#imgrc=bjIUmRMBCRFhuM%3A

Comment: @AlexMathers: contour now depicted.

Comment: If not disturbing, can you tell me how can you make the picture? I am trying to learn to drawing nowadays, but  still can't find a nice program. (Rotating area, etc). Thanks.

Comment: @studentforever: I used the *export* functionality of Geogebra (https://www.geogebra.org/). It is a pretty, fast and free way for producing simple pictures.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you are not familiar with Cauchy's principal value, you can see you integration as
$$\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(x+1) (x-2)} = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \, \left(\int_0^{2-\delta} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(x+1) (x-2)} + \int_{2+\delta}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(x+1) (x-2)} \right),$$
Which is
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \, \left( \frac{1}{3} (\log (\delta +3)-\log (\delta )) + \frac{1}{3} (-\log (3-\delta )+\log (-\delta )- i \pi -\log (2)) \right).$$
Simplifying we have
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \,  \frac{1}{3} \left(\log \left(-\frac{\delta }{2}\right)-\log (\delta )+2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\delta }{3}\right)-i \pi \right) = -\frac{\log (2)}{3}.$$

Comment: This helps me see why we'd accept the principal value in Jack's answer as correct, but I'm supposed to use residues and integrals so it's not exactly what I'm looking for. But +1 for the effort